# IP deployment tomcat kubernetes

Tags: docker, tomcat, kubernetes, kubeadm

I need that tomcat is registered with my Node IP and a port.

My question is:

At the moment that i run the command:

```
kubectl run tomcat-pod --image=tomcat --port=80 --labels="name=tomcat-pod"
```

In this moment the tomcat is running.

Then I believe that exposing like a service my tomcat with NodePort type, It will change my IP registration, because i have understanded that my server is registered with the command run?

Or what is the correct way to register my app with the Node machine using the tomcat in the container?

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal  and make `Tomcat` deployment available on the Node machine, consider using `Service` type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) to expose Tomcat application server on the `Node IP` address.

Create the manifest file for `Tomcat` application server implementation, ensuring that you remove previous Tomcat deployment:

```
kubectl delete deployment tomcat-pod
```

Manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-pod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: tomcat-pod
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: tomcat-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Create deployment for `Tomcat` in your K8s cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f manifest_file.yaml
```

Compose service exposing your `Tomcat` container port (by default 8080):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-pod
  labels:
    run: tomcat-pod
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: tomcat-pod
```

Create service:

```
kubectl apply -f manifest_file.yaml
```

Check your created service properties: `kubectl describe service tomcat-pod`

```
Name:                     tomcat-pod
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=tomcat-pod
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"run":"tomcat-pod"},"name":"tomcat-pod","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"port...
Selector:                 run=tomcat-pod
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       XXX.XX.XX.XX
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30218/TCP
Endpoints:                XXX.XX.XX.XX:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Now you can reach your Tomcat application server via Node IP address.

Be aware as `NodePort` is randomly selected from the default pool 30000-32767 and this value is unique for each Node in the cluster.

Comment: If I create the pod, the service create the authentication with discovery server. And I don't know Why, but Later of the pod I create the service. And the discover shows me the POD IP Not my server IP

Comment: Is possible create first the service, and later de pod? to authenticate in the discover server with NodePort and not with the container IP and container port